# Why isn't my 'frame_change' app handler working?

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I am new to scripting in Blender and I am having trouble attaching an app handler to keyframe changes during an animation.

Below is my Python code:

```
import bpy

def my_handler():
    bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location[0] += 0.5

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

I tried to call `my_handler`, which moves an object when the frame changes, manually or when the animation starts.

I have written the code in text editor. After I run script, nothing really happens. Please help me someone out there I couldn't find anything online.

Comment: As an addendum to answer below, for the most part the argument passed  is the scene object.  (is shown as **dummy** in  load handler examples, where it has value None).  For all other handlers the scene passed as argument `def handler(scene):`  `cube = scene.objects.get("Cube")` will be the object if it is in the scene, None otherwise.   Without  this the object will move when changing frame on any scene. Also recommend  something like `cube.location.x = scene.frame_current * 0.5` to stop the object moving collectively further away every frame change. (or reset  at a certain frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in the documentation at https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html :

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    print("Load Handler:", bpy.data.filepath)

bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)
```

handlers need an argument.

You probably do not need it persistent, but you need the `dummy` part. This will work:

```
import bpy

def my_handler(dummy):
    bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location[0] += 0.5

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```